# SharePoint 2013 Scheduled Crawls not working

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, crawl

I implemented the SharePoint Crawl on my dev-server. It working fine if we run the crawal manually. I added Scheduled to run the crawl after 10 minutes but its not working. It just show the next Incremental crawl. But the latest added files are not get searched on SharePoint site. 
Can you please help how I can fix this issues?

Below error are showing in Crawl Log:
3 Access is denied. Verify that either the Default Content Access Account has access to this repository, or add a crawl rule to crawl this repository. If the repository being crawled is a SharePoint repository, verify that the account you are using has "Full Read" permissions on the SharePoint Web Application being crawled.

1 This item could not be crawled because the repository did not respond within the specified timeout period. Try to crawl the repository at a later time, or increase the timeout value on the Proxy and Timeout page in search administration. You might also want to crawl this repository during off-peak usage times.

1 Error in the Microsoft SharePoint Server People Protocol Handler.

1 Processing this item failed because of a IFilter parser error.

Comment: In search administration you can test if the items are part of the index. Do they show up? Do you get any crawl errors?

Comment: @MarekSarad In search administration items are showing. In Crawl log I seeing below errors

Comment: It is better to update the question with the errors than put it in the comments. But so I understand you correctly. So are the items crawled or you getting errors. When you check the crawl log for particular document (using url) do you get success or one of the errors mentioned? If you get success then item is crawled and actually what your problem is that search web part is not retrieving the item (it may be duplicate and this is why it is trimmed?) I hit that hole in the past during testing I used same file and search was returning only one due to duplicate trimming.

Comment: @MarekSarad I updates my questions with error. I am getting always these error. If I am running crawl is working fine but what  issues can be there in scheduler.

Comment: It is very strange behavior, manual crawl should work the same as scheduled. Unless you have some issue with the timer service on the crawl server, is it running under correct account?

Comment: yes it running under correct account.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your crawl service account doesnt have enough permission on User Profile Service Application.

GO to Central Admin --> Manage Service Applciations.

Dont click on user Profile Service applciation just select it and you will see Administrators option on top . 
Click to open it . Make sure your crawl service account is added over there and has following permissions ticked .

1. Retrieve people data for search crawlers
2. manage social data.

Let me know if this does not solve your problem.

Comment: I am facing issues the error  "The search application 'Search Service Application' on server dev-app-sp did not finish loading". Can you please advise how I can resolve this issues?

Comment: Run the product configuration tool once. This will solve your problem